# spring-rabbit - XSD lacks rabbit:listener error-handler?

Tags: spring-rabbit

Spring Rabbit has RabbitListenerErrorHandler which is configurable via Java @Configuration via @RabbitListener. Example

```
@RabbitListener(containerFactory="listenerContainerFactory",
            queues="${listener.queue}",
            errorHandler="listenerErrorHandler")
```

Where is the corresponding "error-handler" attribute of rabbit:listener element in XSD schema?

XML configuration example. Note - the lowever level "error-handler" attribute for rabbit:listener-container exists.

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"
            error-handler="containerErrorHandler">
        <rabbit:listener queues="${listener.queue}" ref="rabbitListener" method="handle" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

The missing error-handler:

```
<rabbit:listener error-handler="listenerErrorHandler" ...  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RabbitListener` uses a more advanced listener adapter (`MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`) that supports `RabbitListenerErrorHandler`.

The legacy `MessageListenerAdapter` (used by the XML config) does not support it.

The annotation model was added many years later.

Comment: Any clue if MessageListenerAdapter will be updated au-pair with MessagingMessageListenerAdapter ?

Comment: No, there are no plans to do so; usage of XML configuration has declined significantly over the last several years; it is still supported, but only in maintenance mode.